# How to put an array of elements from enum values defined in RAML?

Tags: arrays, json, api, enums, raml

I'm stuck in one point developing this RAML thing. In my included JSON to test the hierarchy of the RAML objects I need to construct like this:

```
"communicationWays": [
   {
     "SMS": false,
     "EMAIL": true,
     "VOICE": false,
     "MAIL": false
   }
 ]
```

But my question is: how can I implement it on RAML part?? I think about something like this...

```
types:
  communicationWays:
    type: array
      items:
        enum:
        - "SMS"
        - "EMAIL"
        - "VOICE"
        - "MAIL"
          (empty type name?)
            type: boolean
```

But, obviously, **this is incorrect**. I'm just try to explain the structure with the code. I tried to find out in the official RAML documentation but I couldn't see this example case.

Can you help me, please, with this kind of structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RAML (1.0) for your requirement will be :

```
        body:
          application/json:
            type: object
            properties: 
              communicationWays:
                type: array
                items:
                  type: object
                  properties:
                    SMS:
                      type: boolean
                      required: false
                    EMAIL:
                      type: boolean
                    VOICE:
                      type: boolean
                    MAIL:
                      type: boolean
```

Instead of enum it will be an object which contains boolean elements.

Comment: What if the API needs that elements to be optional?

Comment: add  "required: false"  as default value of required is true (updated the snippet)